# Error 1004 when argument variable reaches a certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error for the following code:

```
For Each Cell1 In Orderrange

    If Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Range("A" & sourcecount) = Cell1.Value Then
      dat = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 1).Value
    End If
    ordercount = ordercount + 1
 Next Cell1
```

`dat = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 1).Value` is highlighted by compiler.

However when i limit the values for variable ordercount the code executes (ordercount is Long, declaring it as Integer gives overflow error). 
the following code works:

```
For Each Cell1 In Orderrange

  If Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Range("A" & sourcecount) = Cell1.Value Then

    If ordercount > 1000 Then
      ordercount = 1000
    End If


    dat = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 1).Value

 End If
 ordercount = ordercount + 1
Next Cell1
```

Following is the complete code:

```
Sub Resolve_Onorder()

'Import source range------------------------------
Dim LastRow1 As Long
LastRow1 = Worksheets("Stock Summary").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Dim Sourcerange As Range
Set Sourcerange = Worksheets("Stock Summary").Range("A2:A" & LastRow1)
'-------------------------------------------------

'Export source range to worksheet-----------------
Dim C1 As Long
C1 = 2
For Each Cell In Sourcerange
    Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Range("A" & C1) = Cell.Value
    C1 = C1 + 1
Next Cell
'-------------------------------------------------

'Import week number-------------------------------
Dim Wknum As Integer
Dim Wknum1 As Integer
Dim Wknum2 As Integer
Dim Wknum3 As Integer
Dim Wknum4 As Integer

Wknum = Worksheets("MPS").Range("C2").Value
Wknum1 = Wknum + 1
Wknum2 = Wknum + 2
Wknum3 = Wknum + 3
Wknum4 = Wknum + 4
'-------------------------------------------------

'Import Onorder range------------------------------
Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = Worksheets("Onorder").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
Dim Orderrange As Range
Set Orderrange = Worksheets("Onorder").Range("C2:C" & LastRow2)
'-------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------
Dim sourcecount As Long
Dim ordercount As Long
Dim ordercoldate As Long
Dim ordercolqty As Long
Dim ordercolrec As Long
Dim dat As String
Dim qty As String
Dim req As String

Dim tdat As String

Dim Colstr As String
Colstr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

sourcecount = 2
ordercount = 2
ordercoldate = 2
ordercoldate = 2
ordercolqty = 8
ordercolrec = 14

While sourcecount <= LastRow1
    ordercoldate = 2
    ordercolqty = 8
    ordercolrec = 14

    '''''''''''''''''''
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    '''''''''''''''''''

    For Each Cell1 In Orderrange

        If Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Range("A" & sourcecount) = Cell1.Value Then
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Worksheets("VBAhide").Range("A" & i).Value = ordercount
            i = i + 1
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            MsgBox "Reached"
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercoldate).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 7).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("G" & ordercount).Value
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercolqty).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 8).Value  'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("H" & ordercount).Value
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercolrec).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 10).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("J" & ordercount).Value
            MsgBox "Reached2"

            ordercoldate = ordercoldate + 1
            ordercolqty = ordercolqty + 1
            ordercolrec = ordercolrec + 1
        End If
        ordercount = ordercount + 1
    Next Cell1
    sourcecount = sourcecount + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: how is `dat` declared?

Comment: dat is a string

Comment: what description follows error 1004?

Comment: “Application-defined or object-defined error.”

Comment: is your code limited to what you showed? or is it acting on `Worksheets("Onorder")`? What's the purpose of that piece of code?

Comment: I think you should check the `ordercount`, and reset that before `For Each Cell1 In Orderrange`

Comment: Oh that's is a great observation. Thanks. The code executed without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercoldate).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 7).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("G" & ordercount).Value
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercolqty).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 8).Value  'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("H" & ordercount).Value
            Worksheets("Resolve Orders").Cells(sourcecount, ordercolrec).Value = Worksheets("Onorder").Cells(ordercount, 10).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("J" & ordercount).Value
```

to

```
            With Worksheets("Resolve Orders")
                .Cells(sourcecount, ordercoldate).Value = Cell1.Offset(, 4).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("G" & ordercount).Value
                .Cells(sourcecount, ordercolqty).Value = Cell1.Offset(, 5).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("H" & ordercount).Value
                .Cells(sourcecount, ordercolrec).Value = Cell1.Offset(, 7).Value 'Worksheets("Onorder").Range("J" & ordercount).Value
            End With
```

and get rid of `ordercount`

Comment: the source and the destination cells are both on different worksheets. I think what you have suggested is true for duplicating values in the same worksheet. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `.Cells(sourcecount, ordercoldate).Value `, being inside a `With Worksheets("Resolve Orders")` _block_ and with a trailing dot actually refers to a `Resolve Orders` range, while `Cell1` is looping through `Orderrange` which was formerly defined as a range of `Worksheets("Onorder")`. So they are point to different worksheets. try and see the results

Comment: @MaherJiwani, did you get through it?

Comment: I wasn't resetting ordercount as rightly pointed out by Alex, which seemed like the easier edit compared your suggestion. since I only just started vba, I was content with a working code, and didnt risk making too many changes for a better code. Thanks a mil! next time I'll use your method in copying values.

Comment: I agree it was the easier edit. But it leaves you with a weak code, since you're not exploiting references to objects you created (in this case, `Cell1` and `Worksheets("Resolve Orders")`). This will sooner or later lead you to debugging problem.